Condition for $ \frac{1}{\pi} \operatorname{Arg}(z) \in \mathbb{Q} $ for $ z $ with $ z^n \in \mathbb{R} $
Let $ z $ be a complex number such that $ z^n \in \mathbb{R} $ for some natural number $ n $ and $ z \neq 0 $.
Does this condition implies that $ \frac{1}{\pi} \operatorname{Arg}(z) \in \mathbb{Q} $?

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Yes.
Let $z = [R, \phi] \in \mathbb{C}$. Note that
$$ [R^n, n \cdot \phi] = z^n \in \mathbb{R} $$
$$ \implies n \cdot \phi = 2\pi \cdot k (k \in \mathbb{Z}) $$
$$ \implies \arg(z) = \phi = \frac{2k \pi}{n} $$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{\pi}\arg(z) = \frac{2k}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} \; (k, n \in \mathbb{Z}) $$

If z^n=k then there are n zs so hiw di we define arg(z) which root of z^n do we pick?

@Goaki I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the fact that there are multiple $n$ with $z^n = 0$?

From $z^n=k$ we get that there are n zeds such that z^n=k, their args are different so how do we define arg(z) when there are n different args?

@Goaki the problem statemenet gives us a fixed $z$ with the property $z^n = r \in \mathbb{R}$
